# Getting emailaddress out of string

Tags: email, grails, groovy

How can I get the email address out of a string like:

```
def emailAddress="john@doe.com <\john@doe.com\\>"
```

so that I can use it in a call to `Contactperson.findByEmailAddress(variable)`

Comment: Are you looking for a RegEx to extract an email from a String?

Answer (score 2):

JavaMail provides a class for representing email addresses that can parse strings in the format you have.  Take a look at [`javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress`](http://javamail.kenai.com/nonav/javadocs/javax/mail/internet/InternetAddress.html).

Grails has a [mail plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/mail) that will automatically make JavaMail available.

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution is

```
Contactperson.findByEmailAddress(emailAddress.split('<')[0])
```

But you need to do some validation work first to avoid format errors.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming the email you need to compare is inside the brackets:

```
Contactperson.findByEmailAddressIlike('%<${variable}>%')
```

You'll probably need to escape the special characters depending on your database.